# Entity Framework: Get Inherited Types directly through Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a TPT inheritance structure which allows me to query inherited objects in the context like this:

```
from test in Context.TestBase.OfType<DerivedType1>()
select test
```

Would it be possible for me to add these inherited types to the base context such that I can query like this:

```
from test in Context.DerivedType1
select test
```

Edit: To be clear, this is a database first structure.

Answer (score 4):

With `DbContext` and `DbSet` (EF 4.1+ and EF 5.0) yes. With `ObjectContext` and `ObjectSet` no unless you wrap your first query to a property but it will allow only querying but not adding, attaching or deleting. `ObjectSet` allows exposing only base types but `DbSet` allows exposing derived types directly as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've been looking around and am not finding what I'm looking for with including the DbContext, DbSet as helpful parameters in my search. Do you have a reference off hand?